# What provides /etc/exports and how do I find that out?

Tags: debian, apt, nfs

I have two Debian virtual machines that were built from the same netinstall iso, but probably have different packages installed.  One of them has an `/etc/exports` file for nfs mounts but the other one doesn't. I would like them both to have this file as installed by the package manager.

I come from the Fedora world and were I still in it, I would `yum whatprovides /etc/exports`. [I am told](http://nicholaskuechler.com/2011/02/10/debian-ubuntu-equivalents-of-yum-whatprovides/) that in Debian land, I should do `apt-file search`. However, I am not getting any results with:

```
apt-file update
apt-file search /etc/exports
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you're looking for a file belonging to a package which is installed on your machine, you can use `dpkg -S` (equivalent to `dpkg-query -S`):

```
dpkg -S /etc/exports
```

In this case though it won't find anything, because `/etc/exports` is created by a maintainer script (and that type of file is explicitly not handled by `dpkg-query`, or for that matter by `apt-file`).

So if `apt-file` and `dkpg -S` fail to find a file, you can try to look through the maintainer scripts:

```
grep /etc/exports /var/lib/dpkg/info/*
```

This should match `nfs-kernel-server`'s maintainer scripts; that's the package which creates `/etc/exports`, at least on my NFS servers.

Answer (score 6):

On Debian, `/etc/exports` is not included in any package.  There is a sample config file:

```
/usr/share/nfs-kernel-server/conffiles/etc.exports
```

You can copy this to /etc/exports and edit it to your satisfaction (there may very well be some nfs post-install set-up which copies this to `/etc`).  This file is provided as part of the `nfs-kernel-server` package:

```
$ apt-file search /usr/share/nfs-kernel-server/conffiles/etc.exports
nfs-kernel-server: /usr/share/nfs-kernel-server/conffiles/etc.exports
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `apt-file`, and if the package you’re looking for is not installed (then `dpkg -S` is your friend), you can look at the Debian website for the file:

[`https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=/etc/exports&mode=path&suite=unstable&arch=any`](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=/etc/exports&mode=path&suite=unstable&arch=any)

It may be more easy to use the web form though (I have a shell function that expands to this URL in `$BROWSER` for me):

- https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents (also on https://packages.debian.org/) for oldstable, stable, testing, unstable, experimental and related backports
- http://archive.debian.net/#search_contents for older Debian releases, such as sarge, etch, lenny, …

As for `/etc/exports` – as the above sites show, it is not contained directly in any package. However, if you have the package already installed, you can grep for it in maintainer scripts:

```
fgrep -r etc/exports /var/lib/dpkg/info
```

The result contains `/var/lib/dpkg/info/nfs-kernel-server.postinst`, which points to our, by now known, culprit for the file.

Failing that, you can search for similarily named files on the website. [This search for “packages that contain files whose names contain the keyword”](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=exports&mode=filename&suite=stable&arch=any) has too many results, but searching for [paths ending with the keyword](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=exports&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any) has only 14 results, one of which is `/usr/share/nfs-kernel-server/conffiles/etc.exports nfs-kernel-server [not kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386]`, which is what we were looking for.

AIUI there is no web-based search over all packages’ maintainer scripts (yet?).

Answer (score 0):

in Ubuntu 20.04 the file */etc/exports* belongs to the package **nfs-kernel-server**

```
sudo apt install nfs-kernel-server
```

to get one installed

Answer (score 0):

The file `/etc/exports` is a configuration file.
Since no filesystems are exported by default, this file is by default either not created or contains only comments.

If you want something exported from your VMs, you should create the file and make sure relevant NFS server packages are installed and enabled.  If you don't want to export any NFS filesystems, then you don't need this file.